# IntelliJ IDEA not recognizing JavaFX library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am attempting to create a JavaFX project using IntelliJ IDEA. The instructions for doing so appear here: [Create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html). This issue is, I am encountering a popup that does not appear in the official instructions, and it is preventing me from using the library.

This is the step I am having trouble with:

[image]

However, when I select the lib folder, I see this popup before I am allowed to proceed and pick a module:

[image]

No matter which option I pick, the classes from that library are still not recognized in the program. What do I do?

Edit: The lib folder is not empty, so that can't be the cause of the issue.

Comment: It may be because the folder you selected is empty.  You need to download the JAVA FX SDK, unzip the SDK and select the lib dir. If I give dir with no jars - the error popsup, with correct lib dir it works fine

Comment: @PrasadU Is the lib folder supposed to be empty by default, because I haven't modified it in any way, and I don't think that it is empty. I am able to open it and it contains a collection of JAR files. There is also another folder inside of it called src, but that folder isn't empty either.

Comment: @PrasadU I just realized that although the folder is not empty, it appears empty on IntelliJ, but not in the file explorer. Why is this?

Comment: Tip: You might find it easier to use [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), and create a project using one of the JavaFX archetypes. See [tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to the lib folder select all .jar files and src.zip file then press ok. You have to manually add all files in the lib folder.